# How to clearcontents of a merged cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to clear contents from cells but some of them are merged so I am getting the error

> 1004 :"We cant do that to merged cells"

```
For l = 4 To 9
    If ws.Cells(j, l).Interior.ColorIndex = 19 Then
         ws.Range(j, l).ClearContents  'Error here
    End If
Next l
```

Another Try using `.Cells` still it returns error

```
    For l = 4 To 9
        If ws.Cells(j, l).Interior.ColorIndex = 19 Then
             ws.Cells(j, l).ClearContents  'Error here
        End If
    Next l
```

Comment: You'll have to loop through each cell. Merged cells are the devil's work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need `Cells` not `Range`:

```
ws.Cells(j, l).ClearContents
```

Oops - forgot about the merged bit:

```
        If Cells(j, l).MergeCells Then
            Cells(j, l).MergeArea.ClearContents
        Else
            Cells(j, l).ClearContents
        End If
```

Comment: initially it was this way then I changed to Range to see if it works then also it didn't work

Comment: @GordonBell no it doesn't. That's not valid `Worksheet.Range` syntax.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, ws.Range("NamedRange").MergeArea.ClearContents works.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Range("A1:A20").Value = ""
```

No matter cells are merged or not this will work everytime.

Answer (score 0):

```
For l = 4 To 9
    If ws.Cells(1, l).Interior.ColorIndex = 19 Then
        ws.Cells(1, l).UnMerge
        ws.Cells(1, l).ClearContents
    End If
Next l
```

You can use unmerge method before clear.

Comment: the UnMerge could be unwanted, and is not mentioned in the question (it could be added after the answer as "additional information", that would be a nice touch!). The For loop and the If condition are not related to the issue. When answering it's better to focus on the OP needs!

Answer (score 0):

I would do [J4].value = 0 then format cell ,the merge cell, Custom to 0;;0

Answer (score 0):

Range("i" & (5) & ":j" & (5)).ClearContents
this worked for me

I merged the cell i5 with cell j5 and the original code was
Range("i5").ClearContents
that doesn't work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

One more thing you create macro and use shortcut key (ctrl + m) so you can select cells that you want merge and clear also.here is this code:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+m
'
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        If .MergeCells = True Then
            .MergeCells = False
        Else
            .MergeCells = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
ws.Range(j, l).Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

If Sheet Name.Range("cell no").MergeCells Then
Sheet Name.Range("cell no").MergeArea.ClearContents
Else
Sheet Name.Range("cell no").ClearContents
End If

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and I could solve it with the following instruction:

```
ws.Range("D10:F1000") = vbNullString
```

Change the range and adapt it to your problem. It supports merge cells in the range area.

Answer (score -3):

Try using

```
ws.Range(j,l).Clearcontents
```

Comment: Oh, I see what you have done now. good update. Problem is probably that you are asking excel to clear the contents of a single cell in a merged cell, which I do not now how to solve. Sorry.