# VBA Delete Cells with MsgBox?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete cells in a table.
The worksheet line is marked as debug.
but i can't find my mistake...

Code:

```
Sub clear_click()
If MsgBox("Del?", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
   Exit Sub
Else

Worksheets("calc").Range("G9:G12").ClearContents
  
End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Is `calc` worksheet in the workbook that runs the code? Try to fully qualify the range. Also, what error did you get?

Comment: @RaymondWu yes its in the workbook

Comment: Try `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("calc").Range("G9:G12").ClearContents` in this case, please provide the error code and description if this doesn't resolve it. @Devo23

Comment: Unfortunately does not work..
Runtime Error 1004

Comment: the code is in a module. is that wrong?

Comment: Please give the error description, we don't remember every single error code in every context. @Devo23

Comment: @RaymondWu
Run-time error '1004': We Can't do that to a merged cell

Comment: There you go - `G9:G12` is merged with some other cells and thus can't be cleared. Is the merged cell's range constant?

Comment: Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169215/how-to-clearcontents-of-a-merged-cells) and see if it can help you.

Comment: @RaymondWu
Another programming writes data into it.
With this button I want to empty the content again.

Comment: Follow the answer in the link I gave you in my previous comment. Without more info of how your cells are merged, it's difficult to help you properly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.